# How to linearize logarithmic DC signal?

Tags: analog, pwm, linearity, signal-conversion, signal-conditioning

I am modifying a cheap Chinese CNC mini-router controller to be able to control the spindle speed with a PWM signal. In theory the spindle controller board has all the electronics already on it to be able to do this but it just wasn't connected. However it didn't quite work as expected. I was able to control the speed but was never able to reach maximum speed. Here's the reverse engineered PWM to analog circuit on the spindle controller:

[image]

The opto-isolator on the board is actually something else but I couldn't find a SPICE model for it so I just used 4N25 instead. I don't think that really matters here anyway...

So it's essentially just a low pass filter and without a load it appears to do what you would expect. With 0% PWM duty cycle you get near 5V and with 100% you get near 0V out from the net labelled LP in the above picture.

However when this was connected directly (original design) to the analog input of the on-board micro controller (STC15W408AS), the LP only went down to about 2.5V preventing the spindle from ever reaching more than 60% speed. I can't really explain why the voltage wouldn't go lower than that. Something to do with the ADC input impedance?

Anyway. I decided to wire in a voltage follower op-amp circuit with a bit of signal scaling and biasing between the LP and the micro controller as follows:

[image]

This allows me to reach the full speed range from 0-100%. However the PWM duty cycle to spindle speed response isn't quite right. It feels like the micro controller is expecting a linear DC signal but this circuitry is producing a logarithmic signal.

I have no means to get into the micro controller firmware to change anything so my question is: Is there a simple way to linearize either the LP signal or the OUT signal from my op-amp?

EDIT1:

I forgot to mention that before I put this Op-Amp circuit in, I had a simple 5K trimmer connected to the ADC input of the micro controller. I also have a display attached to the spindle controller board that shows me the output speed of the spindle as percentage.

With the trimmer I figured out that the expected voltage range to the ADC is from about 3.68V (0% speed) to 1.88V (100% speed). With that in mind I tried to scale and bias the (unloaded) output of the low pass filter to the same sort of range (R6, R7 and R8)... I think I got close enough...

Anyway, here's a graph showing the input PWM duty cycle vs. what the display says:

[image]

Ideally the percentages should match but it doesn't really have to be super accurate. The 90-100% range is a bit funny. There doesn't really seem to be any room for adjustment. It's either 90% or 100%. I suppose this is done intentionally in the firmware.

For what it's worth, here's a graph of the OpAmp output voltage during the above experiment.

[image]

Here's the data as CSV:

```
Input PWM,Op-Amp Out,Display
0.00%,4.010V,0.00%
5.00%,3.579V,4.00%
10.00%,3.167V,25.00%
15.00%,2.838V,42.00%
20.00%,2.617V,54.00%
25.00%,2.465V,62.00%
30.00%,2.366V,65.00%
35.00%,2.307V,68.00%
40.00%,2.251V,71.00%
45.00%,2.198V,74.00%
50.00%,2.149V,76.00%
55.00%,2.103V,79.00%
60.00%,2.060V,81.00%
65.00%,2.021V,83.00%
70.00%,1.986V,85.00%
75.00%,1.954V,87.00%
80.00%,1.927V,88.00%
85.00%,1.904V,90.00%
90.00%,1.886V,90.00%
95.00%,1.874V,100.00%
100.00%,1.870V,100.00%
```

Comment: The way to do it depends entirely on what needs to be done so, I would suggest, you draw a graph of what currently happens and explain how you want that graph to change. Be precise because the devil will be in the detail entirely.

Comment: That seems like an altogether inappropriate amplifier for this application- you want both rail-to-rail input and output, and there is no need for such high output current capability.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thank you. I haven't got a lot of op-amps at hand so I just used this one I found in my box as it at least works with single supply and has rail-to-rail output. Totally open to better suggestions!

Comment: There are many, for example, LMC6482, MCP6002 (both duals).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thank you. I will look into those. The input range actually doesn't need to be rail to rail anyway. I'll add some graphs to the question later when I have them.

Comment: The circuit you show has an output that goes from almost zero to within 300mV of the 5V rail. The input has to work over that range for the voltage follower to work reliably.

Comment: @Andyaka I have added more information, graphs etc to the question.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany You're right that electronically that should be the case. But I've now added a bit more information to the question that explains the situation a bit more. I suppose the output doesn't have to be rail to rail either in this case. I just put it in because I couldn't get it to work properly with another op-amp, which I can't now remember what it was...

Answer (score 0):

I think systems with negative feedback are generally very linear. You could arrange feedback. Maybe you could use a Sigma-Delta isolated ADC. It's isolated and you could simply filter out the stream. But actually if this is what you do, maybe you can simply replace the optocoupler and get a clean and accurate signal.